# 'Publish messages' option not available anymore on Google cloud console

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub

On google cloud console, there was a convenient option inside topic details to publish a message.
That option is no longer available.

Is there any alternative convenient way to publish messages on a topic from google cloud console?
Currently it is just showing an option to trigger cloud function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is now in  Messages section at the bottom of the topic details page:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like they have moved that option down on that page along with 'Subscriptions' and 'Snapshots'.